# MapRoute And Master Page (MVC3) - request not working

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, maproute

Good Afternoon,

I have a web application (MVC3) which has master page.

I have the following link localhost/home/index?Id=10

In own master, when I make a request("id") the value returned is 10.

When implemented the route. For the link to become localhost/home/index/10
In the master page of the return request("id") is now empty.

```
routes.MapRoute("index", "home/index/{id}", New With {.controller = "Home", .action = "index"}, New With {.id = "\d+"})
```

How can I fix this request?

Comment: Why are you using `Request` in your master page? That defies whole idea of MVC. (in fact, you seldom need to use `Request` at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using routes, then you need to request the *value* associated to your *route token*:

```
this.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"]
```

Comment: It worked very well, congratulations for your knowledge.
Thank Jupaol,